# How can I differentiate between a person's name and other names that are derived from verbs

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

How can I extract person names from the text?

I have applied some NLP toolkit for this, specifically I used the Stanford NER toolkit to extract names from text. With that, I can extract person names from the text, but when I want the program to extract words like 'programmer', 'lecturer' or 'engineer', the libraries couldn't extract those. Is there any way to extract these from the text?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since "Programmer, lecturer, and engineer" are not named-entities,  you may have to maintain a list of those words. I think you can obtain them from word derivation relationships in Wordnet, like "sing" (verb) and "singer" or "lecture" (verb) and "lecturer" (noun).

A [SuperSense tagger](http://medialab.di.unipi.it/wiki/SuperSense_Tagger) may also be used as NER, I think it can tag those words you mentioned as "noun.person" which is what you need. [ArkRef](http://www.ark.cs.cmu.edu/ARKref/) (Java) is a coreference tool that uses it (through a Java port of supersense tagger, bundled), and there's an online demo there, so you can check if your target words are tagged in square brackets.

Comment: owky, thanks Kenston. I will give it a try ..

Comment: is there any tutorial for applying this toolkit

Comment: I used it from ArkRef which includes the supersense tagger, but you can use the unbundled one. I haven't checked if there's a tutorial for that. But if you're using it from ArkRef, you can try figuring it out from source code.

Comment: owky, in the package there is no documentation as well. any other tool that i can use which use java.

Comment: I think it would be easier if you harvest the list from WordNet since it has the "word derivation" relationship, although it may require some filtering task.

Comment: Also, you can check the supersense model file, extract the one for noun, and find entries with "noun.person", you may need to do some filtering though. The purpose of the supersense tagger is to provide some disambiguation as well. Not sure if there's an API to retrieve them for you.

Comment: if you don't mind could you provide me with a simple example which retrieve those names from the text.

Comment: You can base the source code from ArkRef, though you have to find it on your own. You can search the codes for keywords like supersense, there should be a text file being generated.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8562/discussion-between-user1234770-and-kenston)