# Detect a pronoun and its noun?

Tags: java, nlp, weka, stanford-nlp

Wondering if there is any tool that can help me to detect a pronoun's name in a text.

Example

```
Jone is Spanish. He can speak German.
```

How can I tag `He` to `Jone`?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem you are trying to solve is known as [anaphora resolution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anaphora_%28linguistics%29#Anaphor_resolution). A java tool to perform this task is available [here](http://aye.comp.nus.edu.sg/~qiu/NLPTools/JavaRAP.html). The source code is made available on that site. For a theoretical look at how it works, check out [this paper](http://acl.ldc.upenn.edu/J/J94/J94-4002.pdf) by Lappin and Leass from 1994.

Comment: is it the only tool that can do the anaphora resolution. Is there any other tools available..

Comment: @user1234770 not at all, there are many. If you feel like diving in to a rich api, the stanford javaNLP suite has a tool called dcoref. You can read about it [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/dcoref.shtml) and read the javadocs [here](http://nlp.stanford.edu/nlp/javadoc/javanlp/). Happy hunting.

Answer (score 5):

Are you looking for coreference resolution tools?
There's a short [blog](http://www.minvolai.com/blog/2010/09/coreference-resolution-tools-a-first-look/) on some of the available tools. Most are written in Java like ArkRef, BART, and the one included in the Stanford CoreNLP.

Comment: Hi Kenston. i have tried Stanford CoreNLP, it works for me, but still not detect names that are coming from verbs, such as lecturer, singer ext... do you think the other tools are able to detect those names !

Comment: You can read my answer for your similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9561370/how-can-i-differentiate-between-a-persons-name-and-other-names-that-are-derived/9561664#9561664

Answer (score 2):

Here is another tool for coreference analysis (aka anaphora resolution): The **[Pronoun Annotator](http://vega.soi.city.ac.uk/~abdy181/software/#pronoun)**, which must be used as part of the [GATE](http://gate.ac.uk/) framework.